# “Bad message” when trying to access a directory on external hard drive

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm running a media server using a Raspberry Pi 4 with an external hard drive connected via USB 3.0.

One issue I've been seeing for a while is "Bad message" returned when I try to ls or stat inside a certain directory inside my (ext4 formatted) external hard drive.

[image: Bad message when trying to list directory]

---

The odd thing is that restarting the system appears to fix the issue 100% of the time I see it occur. (I also don't have the fsck value set in fstab for the drive, so I don't believe it's being run on boot for that drive)

[image: Working after a restart]

Also, I even went as far as to repair the filesystem and even *swap out the entire disk itself with a new one* (using the same enclosure), format it again, and am still seeing the issue!

Obviously this leads me to believe it's unlikely to be a hardware issue (although I suppose it still could be the enclosure or something, but I don't see why a reboot would be likely to fix that).

I'm running some Docker containers that all use the hard drive (Radarr, Sonarr, etc.). Could this be due to a process keeping a file handle open? A corrupted file being downloaded somewhere inside?

Should I consider another file system format like NTFS or VFAT?

Could it be the way I automount the drive (e.g. my flags in `/etc/fstab`)?

Thanks for any help. I'm a bit stumped and this has been annoying me for months now.

Comment: Are you aware of the [issues](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=245931) affecting some external USB3 enclosures on the Raspberry Pi 4 that can lead to file system corruption?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thanks - I have seen that thread in the past. I didn't realize it could lead to FS corruption; thought it was only affecting transfer speeds. Maybe I can try that quirks mode and see if that resolves it for now.

Comment: Actually I had forgotten that I already had quirks mode enabled for my enclosure, so that must not be the cause: `usb-storage.quirks=152d:0578:u,152d:1561:u console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=d4b5ead6-01 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait`

Comment: Are you using a different lead for each enclosure?

Comment: I'm using the same enclosure and cable, but I did swap out the internal disk (as I thought the original disk was failing or going bad)